# Mongodb client intermittent connection error

Tags: mongodb

I have a replicaset where there is one primary and two secondary nodes.
Once in a while I am not able to connect to primary and i get this error which goes away after a minute or so and I am able to connect. Any thoughts why this could be happening ?
When this error happens I tried connecting to secondary  and did rs.status which said 
primary is still same server and running ok.

Below is the command text from the console that shows the issue.

```
mongo --host <hostname> --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: <hostname>:27017/test
Sat Mar  2 14:54:02 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Sat Mar  2 14:54:02 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: <hostname>:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:93
exception: connect failed


mongo --host <hostname> --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: <hostname>:27017/test
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: In what language/framework are you developing?

Comment: please check the logs on the primary for the time that your connection failed.